# How to trigger when UITextField in UITableViewCell resignFromFirstResponder

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, uitextfield, snapkit

I have two UITextFields in UITableViewCell, I want to check when the `secondTextField` `resignFromFirstResponder` and both `firstTextField` and `secondTextField` empty, It will show a warning label. Please take a look at my code below.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SnapKit
class TwoTextInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    let firstTextField = UITextField()
    let secondTextField = UITextField()
    let stackView = UIStackView().then {
        $0.axis = .horizontal
        $0.distribution = .fillEqually
        $0.spacing = 15
    }
    let warningLabel = UILabel().then {
        $0.isHidden = true
        $0.addCharacterSpacing(-0.1)
        $0.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        $0.textColor = UIColor.CommonColor.salmonColor
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentView.addSubviews(stackView, warningLabel)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(firstTextField)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(secondTextField)
        stackView.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.left.equalToSuperview().offset(24)
            $0.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-24)
            $0.top.equalToSuperview().offset(12)
            $0.height.equalTo(56)
        }
        warningLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.top.equalTo(stackView.snp.bottom).offset(12)
            $0.height.equalTo(16)
            $0.left.right.equalTo(stackView)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Once it resign, I want to make `warningLabel.isHidden = false` and reload tableView height, but how to do it? Any answer is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily achive it by using textfield delegate

confirm to delegates first

```
let firstTextField = UITextField()
let secondTextField = UITextField()
firstTextField.delegate = self
secondTextField.delegate = self
```

observe for textFieldDidEditing Delegate

```
extension TwoTextInputTableViewCell : UITextFieldDelegate{
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
            if textField == firstTextField {
            //first textfield  resignFromFirstResponder
           }else if textField == secondTextField{
           //second textfield  resignFromFirstResponder
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah, I have just found it, but still have problem when update tableViewCell height, how do I know textField in another tableViewCell is focus??